# Java Text Formatting bold

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts, border-layout

I am having a hard time understanding how to bold the text in my GUI program. The program shows the initial value of my calculator program to be 0.0 but I need to be able to make it bold and set it to 14 font. Is there any easy way to do this?

```
JPanel x = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         JTextField z = new JTextField();
         z.setEditable(false);
         z.setText("0.0");
         x.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
z.setFont(z.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 14f));
```

`deriveFont()` has the advantage of being able to base your new font on the existing one.  This will maintain the font characteristics that you don't mean to change.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! I kept forgetting the deriveFont and was putting a comma instead of a period.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change you `JTextField` font by doing the following:

```
f.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));// Tahoma is an example, you could use any forn you want.
```